# Xperia Lounge and bootloader unlocking

Tags: bootloader, sony, sony-xperia

I have unlocked the BL on my F5122 XX Dual and I can't claim that PlayStation Theme (I have Gold Membership on XLounge) with the error "Cannot contact service, try again later". I can do anything else on XLounge like participating in giveaways, download free stuff, etc just that Theme offer. I tried cleaning data, uninstalling updates even a full wipe and locking the bootloader just because of a theme and still couldn't claim it. Is claiming offers tied up with DRM keys which are lost during the BL unlocking?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is right. If you do not have the keys any more then Pass (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonymobile.xperialounge.services) cannot confirm that it is an Xperia phone so you will not be able to download the Playstation Theme for free.